# How to run Node.js app in Android Mobile

Tags: android, node.js, npm, adb

I want to run node.js app in Android mobile.I want to run through adb shell without routing my android device.Please let me know if you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Try this http://masashi-k.blogspot.in/2013/08/nodejs-on-android.html

Comment: I need to root my device to run this example.I want to run without rooting my device.

Comment: Without rooting you need to go with a framework like Anode - https://github.com/paddybyers/anode.